# What code could be used as a string aggregator for Sybase? (Like Oracle's stragg)

Tags: string, sybase, aggregation

In my travels in Oracle, the 'stragg' function, or 'String Aggregator' was life-saving when I had to create dynamic SQL queries on the fly.

You can read up about it here: http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/delimited_lists_to_collections.html

The basic use of it was:

```
select stragg(fruit) from food;

fruit
-----------
apple,pear,banana,strawberry

1 row(s) returned
```

So simple to use, concatenating chr(13) turned it into a long list, and selecting information from system tables gave a 5 minute solution to dynamically generated SQL, e.g. auditing triggers.

Now I've been charged with transferring oracle functionality related to auditing into Sybase, and a function similar to Stragg would be ideal for this purpose.

E.g.

```
select @my_table = 'table_of_fruit'

select 'insert into '+@mytable+'_copy (' +char(10)
   + stragg(c.name) +char(10)
   + 'select '
   + stragg('inserted.'+c.name) + char(10)
   + 'from '+@mytable
from syscolumns c
where objectid(@mytable) = c.id


------------------------------------------
insert into table_of_fruit_copy
(fruit, sweetness, price) 
select fruit, sweetness,price 
from inserted
```

Done. Simple.

Except I don't know how to get a string-aggregation function working in Sybase.

Does anyone know of an attempt to do this kind of thing, or code that could work the same as stragg that could be used in this way?

The alternative at the moment is printing code based on complex cursors and such (sample LOC: 500), or select statements combining static strings and columns from user tables (sample LOC: 200). Stragg would severely reduce the complexity of this code, and would be a great deal of help in the future (sample LOC: who knows, maybe 50?)

p.s. I'm calling these selects through a shell script then piping them to file, then running the file through iSQL. Not the nicest solution, but it's better than the alternatives.

Comment: Nice question. It reminds me of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943181/how-can-i-merge-flatten-or-pivot-results-from-a-query-which-returns-multip. I wish there were a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three separate answers

### Question

You have made comments about simplicity, which need to be addressed before we get to the solution.

> *It is a common requirement to be able to take a delimited list of values, say A,B,C,D, and treat this data like it was a set of rows in a table, or vice versa*

1. This one of the **Top Ten Worst Programming Practices** I read about recently.
2. In general, Sybase types tend to be somewhat more academically and Relationally qualified than Oracle types, so we simply do not do that sort of thing in SybaseLand or DB2Land.
3. In 20 years of working with Sybase, I have had to code that as part of my project just once, and that was for non-technical Auditor who loaded the result set into MS Access.
4. On the other hand, I have had to code that at least 12 times, when producing text files for importation into Oracle databases (fulfilling external requirements is outside my project, but I satisfy any such requirement free).  Obviously the target databases were sub-standard and non-relational (loading a column with more than one datum breaks 1NF, and creates Update Anomalies), which is typical of what Oracle types have to do to get some speed.
5. Therefore, no, it is not simplicity, at least in the sense of that principle.  It is by definition, complexity.
6. Your reference to "arrays" is incorrect.  All commercial dbms handle arrays, according to the ISO/IEC/ANSI SQL (STRAGGR and LIST operators are non-standard SQL, therefore not SQL).  Sybase is very strong in processing arrays.  If it was an array, you would not need special hand coding to handle it (and you do, as per your question). This is not an array, there is no definition to the cells.  This is a single concatenated scalar string.
7. Pivoting is an entirely different process, which uses set-processing; it does not require row-processing. (I understand on good authority, that Oracle is hopeless at scalar subqueries, and thus Oracle people are used to writing them as [very inefficient] joins or inline views, and then filtering: all that can be elevated to set-processing via scalar subqueries, and it will perform **much** faster.  Particularly your Pivots.)
8. Even the author in your link posts as follows.  Please familiarise yourself with the caveats:

> *It's as simple as this: If you want to have a system with no logical limitation in the number of data elements passed to a given process, then forget the following mechanisms! They are simply the wrong way to approach the problem.*

8. Therefore, **know** whatever you are doing is sub-standard, non-relational, and limited; and go ahead with your eyes open.  No use pretending that: it will not break; it is not limited; it is an "array"; or that Sybase doesn't have a neat little function that Oracle has.  Any professional will see through all that.  And if the string length is exceeded, for God's sake send some indicator back to the caller ("!Exceeded" in the string) identifying that condition.
9. Essentially you are turning the set-processing engine on its head, and forcing it into row-processing mode, so it will be very slow.  A WHILE loop is distinctly faster than a cursor, but both are in the same class, row-processors.

> *The alternative at the moment is printing code based on complex cursors and such*

10. What 200 or 500 LoC ?  It is possible I am missing something, but my code is the same few lines of code identified under *"Using a Table Function"* in your link.  **Maximum 20**, if you count nice formatting; the loop; initialisation; error handling.  There is nothing "complex" about it.  Do the exact reverse to cancatenate a single string from multiple rows.  We use stored procedures for this (which oracle does not have, really, PL/SQL is a different animal).  If you have ASE 15.0.2 or greater, you can use a User Defined Function, which you can then use in place of a column.  Stored procs are better for true arrays.

    - the concatenation operator in Sybase is the plus sign. For reversal (decomposing the CSV string) you need CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING functions
    - You may need the [**Function Reference Manual**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/blocks.pdf), if for nothing else, to avoid writing code where we have functions.

Likewise, we do not have a **RANK()** function.  We are quite happy with the 4 lines of code requires for the subquery.  It is only required for Oracle because subqueries are crippled.

---

Ok, I have answered your question, Now to address the approaches.

- You will be aware that code using Oracle **Extensions** to the SQL standard will need to be changed.
- Sybase is way more automated than Oracle; if you familiarise yourself with its feature set, in many instances, you can get the same result (as you did in Oracle) without writing any code.  Writing code-for-code blocks is the chain gang, rock-breaking method of building roads, in the context of bulldozers.  Even if your company had good reason to use that method, you need to the aware that features work quite differently, eg. triggers, which is why I am posting so much detail.
- Another issue that will annoy you is that Oracle isn't really ANSI SQL compliant (stretches the definitions in many places, in order to **appear** to be compliant), and Sybase, given its customer base, is rigidly SQL compliant.  So in addition to the same function working differently, or in a different deployment, you need to be aware that code changes may be required to elevate Oracle code to ANSI compliance levels, just to execute on an ANSI SQL compliant platform.

I am not sure if you are trying to write code for the content of a trigger, or if you are trying to capture the changes to a database.  I will provide both answers.

### Auditing

**Capture Changes to Database**

We have an very robust, fast and configurable Auditing subsystem, fit for high volumes and banking level auditing requirements. Get your DBA to setup the sybaudit (separate) database, and to configure exactly what changes need to be captured.  This facility will perform much faster than any code you or I can write in a trigger (as much as 100 times faster than your row-by-processing required for the above, as it is executed within the engine, within your executing thread).  And of course the setup time is a fraction of your coding time.

### Triggers

Again, I am not sure *exactly* what you are trying to achieve, but assuming you want to copy every insert to some table to a COPY of that table (inside the Trigger), that example code you have provided will not work (and I am not counting syntax issues).

1. Speaking to your example, you need to do **way** more work, to deal with the different datatypes; column sizes; precisions; scale; etc.  And perhaps the UPDATE() function to identify which columns have changed (for an UPDATE trigger of course). If all you are trying to do is convert the various datatypes to strings, check the CONVERT() function.

   - Triggers are transactional.
   - Never place row-processing code in a Trigger (it will strangle the table)
   - You can't place Dynamic SQL in a Trigger.
2. But in Sybase even that is not necessary.  Refer to the [**User Guide**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc32300_1250/pdf/sqlug.pdf), chapter 19 is devoted to Triggers, with several variations, and examples.  Inside the trigger, you should be able to simply:

   ```
   INSERT table_copy
       SELECT column_list  -- never use * unless you want the db fixed in cement
           FROM inserted
   ```
3. If you are trying to copy the inserts to **all** tables into one Audit table, then beware.  Then I understand your example a little bit more.  You will be forcing a highly Symmetric Muli-Threading server (oracle is not a server in the architecture sense) into single-threading through your table.  Auditing is multi-threaded.

Last, the use of manual methods of any kind is not required, so if you could expand a bit more on your PS, what the requirement you are trying to fulfil is, I can identify the programmatic method for you.  It appears you are trying to use the PL/SQL approach (which is very limited).

Comment: Wow.. Ok, I'm going to have to take a bit to digest this, then get back to you. Very thoughtful answer.

Comment: @glasnt Thanks.  Take your time.  I added one para at the end of Question section re RANK() function.

Comment: Righto. I never said anything about arrays or pivot tables. In this particular case, I didn't have anything to do with auditing in mind. This was back on a project to do with security features, and returning information in a nicer way from terminal. All I wanted to do was to get a listing of columns out in a concatenated way, which I could then manipulate from there.

Comment: @glasnt. I am confused, the code supplied is specifically trigger code referencing `inserted`; you were doing some sort of recording of changes to the tables, now your not ?  So it is now manual, not programmatic ?  And the result column is a fixed 80-char width ?  May I ask you to revise the wording in your Question, and I will change my Answer.

Comment: Ah, so I did. As I said, this is a 6 month old question, and I have no idea what I was trying to use this functionality for. I should remove the 'inserted' reference, as a string aggregator function is helpful regardless of it's application

Comment: @glasnt.  Yeah, I was going through and cleaning up unclosed questions, doesn't look like they had any real Sybase expertise before I came here a few weeks ago.  Ok, so you want code for Sybase equivalent of STRAGG() only ?  I can post the code if you like, you can substitute your table_names, etc, but there is no generic solution, no function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `LIST()` function. It's a direct replacement for `stragg()` function.  Example:

```
SELECT LIST(state, ', ') FROM cities
```

Result:

```
name
CA, CA, MA, NY
```

Comment: We don't have a LIST() function in Sybase ASE.  The NONsqls have marvellous extras but not the basics of SQL.

Comment: Works fine in Sybase IQ 16.0 and question doesn't specify ASE or IQ.  Answer is valid, upvoted.